# If radio button checked add new form element using dom?

Tags: javascript, dom

How do I use DOM in Javascript to check if a radio button is checked and then if so add new form elements to datesettings?

```
//Radio buttons
<input type="radio" id="dateoption" name="dateoption" value="1">
<input type="radio" id="dateoption" name="dateoption" value="2">

//Add new form elements
<span id="datesettings"></span>
```

Im currently reading a Javascript book but its not helping me understand. If someone could help me with this example then maybe the penny will drop. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would write a function to do the check, like this:

```
function CheckDateOptions() {
    var o1 = document.getElementById("dateoption1");
    var o2 = document.getElementById("dateoption2");
    var eSettings = document.getElementById("datesettings");
    if(o1.checked) {
        eSettings.appendChild(...);
    }
    else if(o2.checked) {
        eSettings.appendChild(...);
    }
}
```

But, you have to make sure to assign your radio buttons **unique** `id` values.  You can duplicate `name`s to group the radio buttons, but for any element, the `id` should be unique.

```
<form id="TestForm">
    <!-- //Radio buttons -->
    <input type="radio" id="dateoption1" name="dateoption" value="1">Text 1</input>
    <input type="radio" id="dateoption2" name="dateoption" value="2">Text 2</text>
    <!-- //Add new form elements -->
    <span id="datesettings"></span>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

Check out this page:

It explains the process so you understand why you're doing it a certain way, AND it gives good example code.

http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tips/html/finding_the_value_of_a_radio_button.php3

Comment: You'd also have to make sure that the elements ahd the same name/`form` parent.

Comment: thanks :) looks a different way to do it. I cant use this though because i need to add 2 different scenarios to datesettings depending on what radio button is checked. Apparently, innerHTML is not very browser friedly compared to DOM.